# remove image field from register form in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a registration form that need to upload image as profile image during registration, I want to remove this uploading field from registration form as the user can upload it later but the problem is the registration form is connected to image process so the field can not be empty, this is the code for store propose inside registration controller:

```
public function store(RegisterUserRequest $request)
{
    $newUserProfileImagePath = $profileImagePath = App::make('ProcessImage')->execute($request->file('profileimage'), 'images/profileimages/', 180, 180);

    $newUserBirthday = Carbon::createFromDate($request->year, $request->month, $request->day);

    $newUser = $this->dispatchFrom(RegisterUserCommand::class, $request, [
        'birthday' => $newUserBirthday, 
        'profileImagePath' => $newUserProfileImagePath
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('feeds_path');

}
```

How can I give a default value or disconnect it from image process?

Comment: Remove the lines of code linked to processing the image that way they never get called.

Comment: If remove that image I will receive this error: MarshalException in MarshalException.php line 17:
Unable to map parameter [profileimage] to command [App\Commands\RegisterUserCommand]

Comment: Did you also remove `'profileImagePath' => $newUserProfileImagePath`

Comment: yeah I removed that one as well

Comment: Check inside `RegisterUserCommand` it must be explicitly looking for the image to be sent to it

Answer (score 2):

You can set value like this:

$newUserProfileImagePath = $profileImagePath = "any image path";

OR you can try to remove All things about file uploading from this method and from this class "RegisterUserCommand. and after this you are still facing error then please upload "RegisterUserCommand" class. I will give you more instructions.
Happy Coding!